# How to upgrade from elementary OS 5 to 6?

Tags: updates

I want to use elementary OS 6 but I am using elementary OS 5 in my VM on Windows.
What terminal commands do I need to type?

Comment: i'm also interested in upgrade procedure. i hope it's possible..

Comment: Here [reddit_link](https://www.reddit.com/r/elementaryos/comments/k7rkaa/how_easy_will_it_be_to_upgrade_from_eos_5_to_6/) is hot discussion about upgrading eOS from 5 to 6.

Comment: So my questions to Raj are: will I have to create a home partition for every user; why can't I just copy the home directory to an external, then copy it back to the fresh install; will creating a home partition have all of my steam games and settings, my email client settings, my messaging settings, and my calendaring settings? I'd say asking for a friend, but we both know that's not true.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To my huge surprise, I learnt that the only way to move to a new version is to completely re-install the OS. This does not go well with the line **"replacement for Windows and macOS"**, because on those two I don't have to completely wipe my environment on every major update.

Comment: is this permanent, or will they offer upgrades after some time?

Comment: I don't know. You could ask devs on GitHub.

Comment: What? This is so bad. So happy that this is no longer my daily driver. Might just take a further seat back (replace E OS with an alternative) till the devs pull their act together.

Comment: If it's not your daily driver, why bother with OS upgrade?

Comment: @BenoitDuffez why should the latest software version be irrelevant in case it's not a daily driver? I use different OSes for different purposes.

Comment: I'd say: not daily driver = no critical data migration => no problem with a wipe + install latest (hence no OS upgrade). I didn't mean that latest was irrelevant. I was arguing that maybe since it's not a daily driver, the hassle of starting from scratch is not a big deal. For me, it would be, I installed 5 years ago and I'm afraid to lose too much by wiping and starting from scratch.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't have `/home` partition I would simply say forget about it. Take backup of data and format it. but just avoid repeating same mistake because eOS 6.0 is not forever by creating `/home` partition will save you in future.

Answer (score 1):

As @RCKT mentioned in his answer there is an upgrade from 5 to 6 can't be done by using some like `dist-upgrade`.
However, it is a good practice to separate `/home` and in my opinion `/opt` (which I use a lot for custom software) in separated partitions. By the way it's always a good idea to do backups from time to time and maybe hold onto a reinstall script which installs all the software packages back on your device after installations.
This all isn't either intuitive nor user friendly and requires some technical knowledge to some extend.
Luckily it came to my attention that the devs are working on a upgrade mechanic. The progress can be followed on [Github](https://github.com/orgs/elementary/projects/103/views/1). However, the upgrade mechanism most likely will be released for OS 6 or OS 7.