# How to Upgrade From Elementary OS 5 to Elementary OS 6

Tags: system-installation, release-juno, updates, kernel, laptop

I'm using Elementary OS 5 as main OS is there any way I can upgrade it to Elementary OS 6 without losing all of my data and configurations etc etc

Comment: This has been asked a few times on here. Check this question: https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/28297/how-to-upgrade-from-elementary-os-5-to-6. In short the answer is not at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to upgrade. If you have a separate partition for /home filesystem then you could do it. if not it is not possible.

Even i am in same scenario and took backup of my data installed " POP OS " afresh. it is feature rich than Elementary OS 6 (Odin) and gives upgrade option every time there is a new OS Release.

Abandon it for the people who developed it. I hope most people shift away from this distribution. This is huge limitation for users.