# Can I update without losing anything?

Tags: elementary-project

Am I able to update to the latest version of elementaryOS without having to reinstall and lose all of my data? If so, what do I need to do?

Comment: You can backup all your data if you save a copy of your /home folder to another disk. But yes, you'd need to do a fresh reinstall.

Comment: this has already been answered here https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/28297/how-to-upgrade-from-elementary-os-5-to-6
and here 
https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/28297/how-to-upgrade-from-elementary-os-5-to-6